# Login using a table connected through LEFT JOIN in SQL

Tags: php, sql, authentication, session, phpmyadmin

I have a table called "merchant" where before logging in, the system checks for the username and password there to see if they match. the code below checks using SQL SELECT and successfully enters a session if input is correct.

The SQL is `$rowMerchant = $mcMerchant->SelectObj_ByUsrMerchant($db, $usrmerchant);` and you can also see the table and its columns in my screenshot.

Now I want to use a different table with their own username and password but also using some columns of the original table "merchant_branch", hench the LEFT JOIN shown below.

I used the SQL SelectObj_ByUsrMerchantBranch and the lines I changed in my login.vc.php are

```
$rowMerchant = $mcMerchant->SelectObj_ByUsrMerchantBranch($db, $usrmerchant);
$merchantid = $rowMerchant['branchid'];
```

I just swapped merchantid to branchid since thats the unique key in "merchant_branch". I can't login however, what seems to be missing?

**login.vc.php**

```
  if (isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login'] == 'LOGIN')
  {
    $usrmerchant = $_POST['username'] . ' ';

    if ($usrmerchant != '')
    {
      $rowMerchant = $mcMerchant->SelectObj_ByUsrMerchant($db, $usrmerchant);
    }

    if ($rowMerchant['usrmerchant'] != '')
    {
      $passwd = strtoupper(md5($_POST['password'] . $rowMerchant['saltcode']));
      if ($passwd == $rowMerchant['passwd'])
      {
        $merchantid = $rowMerchant['merchantid'];
        $rowAcctCMS = $mcAcctCMS->SelectObj_BySysrefAcctId($db, 1);

        // Assign Session
        $_SESSION['merchantid'] = $merchantid;
        $_SESSION['usrmerchant'] = $rowMerchant['usrmerchant'];
        $_SESSION['accesslevel'] = 'MERCHANT';

        header('Location: orders.php?s=claimed'); die();
      }
```

[image: tables]

**Merchant.mc.php**

*SelectObj_ByUsrMerchant*

```
  " SELECT
      merchantid, usrmerchant, businessname, description, address, contact, email, logosrc, facebook, instagram, linkedin, twitter, googleplus, domainpath, recstatus, CAST(nearby AS UNSIGNED) AS nearby, passwd, saltcode, createddate
    FROM merchant
    WHERE
      usrmerchant = :usrmerchant "
```

*SelectObj_ByUsrMerchantBranch*

```
  " SELECT
      mb.branchid, mb.merchantid, mb.usrmerchant, m.businessname, m.description, m.address, m.contact, m.email, m.logosrc, m.facebook, m.instagram, m.linkedin, m.twitter, m.googleplus, m.domainpath, m.recstatus, CAST(m.nearby AS UNSIGNED) AS nearby, mb.passwd, mb.saltcode, m.createddate
    FROM `merchant_branch` mb
    LEFT JOIN `merchant` m ON mb.merchantid = m.merchantid
    WHERE
      usrmerchant = :usrmerchant "
```